# Do newsstand apps require push notifications?

Tags: iphone, ipad, apple-push-notifications, newsstand-kit

If I submit a newstand app that does not use push notifications, but instead queries my server for new content each time the user launches the app will apple reject my app? 
I.e. Do users expect push on all newsstand apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aroth has answered the question correctly but I want to add few important points to keep in mind for Newsstand apps based on my personal experience.

1. Apple will reject any Newsstand app without subscription in it.
   In case all your content is free still you have to create a Free
   subscription.
2. The content must be a magazine/newspaper/newsletter.No catalog etc
   in Newsstand.
3. The new content must come with frequency of at most a quater.

To answer this question

> Do users expect push on all newsstand apps?

YES they will, because it is one of the most important functionality of NS apps and is assumed by default. Every single NS app in App Store has it.

Answer (score 8):

No, Apple's guidelines do not mandate the use of push notifications, and your app should not be rejected for not using them.  However it may provide a better experience for your users if you implement push notifications.  Otherwise the only way for a user to know that updates are available is to manually run your app and check.

Note that the official [review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) for a Newsstand app are exactly the same as the review guidelines for any other app.

Answer (score 1):

While the technical answer is "no", there is a very good point to implement push notifications. The end user is expecting to see fresh content "magically appearing" in the newsstand applications without actual interaction. For this feature to work, you need to implement background downloading on new issues, data, whatever, which is possible when you have an APNS server informing (and waking up) your application on new content.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that a newsstand app with a method for in app purchase of a Free subscription but without automatic content pushing will not be rejected.

Apple just approved an app I've been working on that only has a Dummy "functionality" for subscribing to Free subscription.
User touches "Subscribe now for free", goes through in app purchase and that's it - nothing changes.
Sole purpose of that button is to get the app approved.

Btw. I've implemented that button only 'cause of this thread.
Thanks!