# Does remote-notification in iOS 7+ require your app to be a Newsstand app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I need to use this API to perform a remote-wipe operation for my app:

Apps that use push notifications to notify the user that new content is available can fetch the content in the background. To support this mode, include the UIBackgroundModes key with the remote-notification value in your app’s Info.plist file. You must also implement the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: method in your app delegate.

However, I saw some posts in a forum that this may require your app to be a Newsstand app.  That said, I couldn't find anything on Apple.com saying that the above API is only for use by Newsstand - indeed, the docs appear to imply this is a general API. Needless to say, my app is not a newsstand app and so want to confirm this officially.

Can anyone confirm this one way or another?  If there is a Newsstand requirement, do you have a link to an Apple.com resource that says that?

Thanks!

Comment: This is general API, not Newsstand only.

Comment: Is your app Newsstand app ? Implementation of remote-notification does not require app to be newsstand app. Without newsstand app has also remote notification. Here is newsstand app with remote notification. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895035/do-newsstand-apps-require-push-notifications?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found very good explanation at [ios-silent-push-notifications link](http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/)!

Difference between normal push and silent push is as follows:

Normal Push:(Payload contains)

aps {
content-available: 1
alert: {...}
}

Silent Push(Payload contains)
aps
{
content-available: 1
}